# Concatenation in Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to concatenate these three columns, but the code i am using is giving me this output, i changed the format of all the columns to string:

```
Income_Status_Number   Income_Stability_Number  Product_Takeup_Number  Permutation
      1                      1                          2                1.012
      2                      1                          3                2.013
      1                      1                          1               1.011
```

this is the code i used:

```
df['Permutation']=df['Income_Status_Number'].astype(str)+""+df['Income_Stability_Number'].astype(str)+""+df['Product_Takeup_Number'].astype(str)
```

But I want my output to look like this:

```
Income_Status_Number   Income_Stability_Number  Product_Takeup_Number  Permutation
  1                      1                          2                     112
  2                      1                          3                     213
  1                      1                          1                     111
```

Please help.

Comment: Better is `df['Permutation']=df['Income_Status_Number'].astype(str)+df['Income_Stability_Number'].astype(str)+df['Product_Takeup_Number'].astype(str)`, but it should working nice.

Comment: What's the purpose of adding `""` between each concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the first column is being treated as a `float` instead of an `int`. The simple way to solve this problem is to sum the values with multipliers to put the numbers is the correct space and let pandas realize that the number is an `int`:

```
df['Permutation'] = df['Income_Status_Number']*100 + df['Income_Stability_Number']*10 + df['Product_Takeup_Number']
```

Another solution is to use `astype(int).astype` to convert the number first, but that solution is somewhat slower:

```
10000 Runs Each

as_type
  Total: 9.7106s
  Avg: 971059.8162ns

Maths
  Total: 7.0491s
  Avg: 704909.3242ns
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first column is being read as a `float` right before you convert it to a string.

```
df['Permutation']=df['Income_Status_Number'].astype(int).astype(str)+df['Income_Stability_Number'].astype(int).astype(str)+df['Product_Takeup_Number'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to add a 'Permutation' column to your data frame formatted in the way you wanted:

```
df['Permutation'] = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)),axis=1)
```

Which give you the following dataframe:

```
df
  Income_Status_Number Income_Stability_Number Product_Takeup_Number  \
0                    1                       1                     2
1                    2                       1                     3
2                    1                       1                     1

  Permutation
0         112
1         213
2         111
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one will work for you.

```
df['Permutation'] = df[df.columns].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)),axis=1)
```